# How to reduce padding between label text and bottom line in TextformField in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, textformfield

This is what I have:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

I want to remove the space between label text and bottom line, how to do that?

[image]

Comment: Both images are the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `InputDecorationTheme` you can style `TextformField` like you want. Also the padding.

Check this out:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecorationTheme-class.html

```
MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(
          inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: 22,
              horizontal: 26,
            ),
            labelStyle: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 35,
              decorationColor: Colors.red,
            ),
        ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use *contentPadding* parameter inside TextField's decoration.For example:

```
    TextField(
        decoration:InputDecoration(
          hintText:"LABEL",
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top:0.0,bottom:0.0)
        ),
       ),
```

You can set content Padding as you like to achieve desired results.

Comment: This only adds additional space, it doesn't remove the spacing that's already there.
But the OP's request can sort of be achieved by adding top padding to push the text down.

Answer (score 1):

Another useful prop in `InputDecoration` is `alignLableWithHint`. This will lower the starting position to the same level as the text/hint text.

Normally the label sits higher, even with contentPadding set to 0

```dart
    TextField(
       decoration:InputDecoration(
         hintText:"some label",
         alignLabelWithHint: true,
       ),
     ),
```

Comment: I would give you more upvotes if I could, I've been wrestling with this for a while and this works a treat.